# Java: Deal with relative filepaths in Eclipse added project

Tags: java, eclipse, file, classpath

I'v added in my eclipse project (Project NEW) code from a previous project (Project OLD) through:

**[Project New] > Build Path > Configure Build Path... > Java Build Path >  Projects > [Old Project]**

However, in my **old project** there are some constant names which reference relative filepaths. Something like this:

```
final static String FILEPATH = "dir/subdir/.."
```

When I test the code in my **Old Project** everything works fine, since the relative filepaths are correctly expanded. However, when I test code in **New Project** (which references code from my **Old Project**), it fails.

This happens because the relative filepath in my **New Project** are expanded by using the prepending the incorrect path (of **New Project**).

e.g.:

```
[New Project's filepath]/dir/subdir/...                      //Wrong
```

insted of:

```
[Old Project's filepath]/dir/subdir/...                       //Right!
```

How to solve that? Thanks for your help.